Minimum Energy required by a particle for its bombardment on a nucleus
I know that a particle (for example proton) should need a minimum kinetic energy(due to the coulombic repulsion) to react with a nucleus. But why we do not write the kinetic energy of the particle bombarded while calculating the energy released or Q-value.
Maybe the kinetic energy would be used in overcoming barrier height. But what if kinetic energy is more than the barrier height then why do we not include the excess kinetic energy in calculations. I am confused that what happens exactly when a particle which is to be bombarded reaches the barrier height, does the fusion immediately takes place or something else?
Also why we do not include Barrier height energy in calculations? Which energy to be included and which not?
For context, I had doubt in the below question.

Actually there is no theory given about calculation of energy during bombardment of particle in my book. Only questions are given about the calculation. I also searched on internet for such theory but I am not getting that. I am a high school student so I am confused. The questions are given for practice to score in exam.
My doubt in the above image is that the kinetic energy of photons and nuclei matters in calculations but then why not the barrier  height as it is also the initial kinetic energy given to the particle. I just want to know more about what happens after particle enters the barrier height. How does the reaction proceed(does the particle bombarded directly hit the nucleus and embed into it or something else)and also please help me about energy calculations in such questions or cases.

Here proton energy is in kinetic or potential form?and what about the kinetic energy of helium nuclei?

The question is just wrong even in the fundamental concepts. Just ignore the question.

Ok I think the question is wrong.

Well it's a rather crude approximation. It's not totally wrong.

@JohnRennie : With all due respect, your calculation does not seem to make sense: 5.60 and 7.06 are BINDING energies per nucleon. That means that, no matter what the energy of the proton, its energy plus energy of Li nucleus is greater than the energy of two He nuclei, so energy is RELEASED in the reaction. As I wrote in my answer, the reaction is possible even when the proton's energy is only about 1 MeV.

@JohnRennie: No, the answer would be -17.28 (not +17.28), which does not make sense. Again, this is an "exothermic" reaction. Again, 5.60 and 7.06 are BINDING energies per nucleon.

Ah, oops, yes I see what you mean. $^8Be_4$ would spontaneously fission into two alpha particles.

@JohnRennie : So maybe the question should be reopened, as the OP asks a reasonable conceptual question about homework?

@akhmeteli no, because a question about the interpretation of a homework question is still homework. You are obviously free to vote to reopen but I doubt you'll find two other like minded people.

@JohnRennie: Thank you.

The current version of the question (v5), without the context of the homework assignment in v3 and earlier, is very hard to interpret.

I may be mistaken, but I suspect there is something wrong with this question. As far as I know, proton energy of about 1 MeV may be enough for this reaction.
EDIT (Nov 28, 2024) : Indeed, this reaction is possible at relatively low proton energiesy. For example, cross-section of this reaction was measured for center-mass energies from 25 to 873 keV in https://doi.org/10.1016/0375-9474(71)90839-6
Again, the test question and the answer to it discussed in OP do not make sense. Apparently, the authors of that question did not realize that they provided binding energies per nucleon, so the initial proton plus 7Li nucleus have higher energy than the final two 4He nuclei.
EDIT (Nov 28, 2024): So the OP edited the question, and it was reopened.

For context, I had doubt in the below question.

The test question does not seem to do anything with your question, as there is no "bombarded" or "bombarding" particle in the test question, there is just the initial nucleus X spontaneously $\alpha$-decaying. Sometimes it emits 1.4 MeV $\alpha$-particle, sometimes it emits an $\alpha$-particle with the energy of just 1 MeV. As the total energy is the same in both cases, the difference between the energies of the $\alpha$-particles is probably the energy of the additional photon produced in the decay.
As for your questions about "bombarded" particles, it would be better if you include a quote from the book (or other source), the quote that you do not understand, as it is not clear if there is an error in your source or in your paraphrase of the source.
The barrier height energy is not included in calculations as it does not affect the energy balance, only cross-sections of reactions.
